# PHPでCSVデータのダウンロードを行う上での達成手順を教えてください

Tags: php, csv

皆様　いつも大変お世話になっております。
こちらの記事　https://blog.supersonico.info/?p=869
を参考にPHPでのCSVデータのダウンロードに挑戦中です。
適用方法が分からなくてお問い合わせさせて頂きました。

こちらの起動を果たすため、当方はHTML兼PHPのWebページに　INPUT要素（SUBMITボタン）を配置して実行するようにしてみました。
すると、CSVファイルは確かに提供されるのですが、以下のコードがそのまま収まって提供されてしまいます。（DOCTYPE htmlから/htmlまで）

===質問===
WebページのINPUT要素（SUBMITボタン）の押下から　この機能を正常に機能させるには
本来どういった適用を行うべきなのでしょうか？
初歩的なことと思いますが　よろしくお願い致します。

====追記=====
実は本件が未だ解決していません．．．というのもCSVデータ云々以前の話で悩んでいて。
cubickさんyyzさんのご見解から、CSV出力指示の画面とCSVデータを提供するPHPを別にしようと考え始めました。
CSV出力指示の画面は、利用者が任意に指定する内容（パラメータ）をTableへ表示するためのsubmitボタンを既に有しており、この隣にCSVデータを出力するためのsubmitボタンを追加で配置しました。

一フォーム内で2つ目のsubmitボタンを配置してしまった為、CSVデータ用途のsubmitボタンを押下しても
Table表示用途のsubmitが押下された際同様　Tableが表示されてしまう事態が起こってしまっています。
かといって、一Webページ内に別フォーム要素を設けて、こちらにCSVデータ出力用のsubmitボタンを格納してしまうと利用者が任意に指定する内容（パラメータ）が元フォーム側に配置しているため利用できない．．．また全く同じDBへのアクセス・SELECT発行なので、Table表示内容のデータ取得部分までは、既存のPHPロジックを活用したい、という点で思い悩んいます。

指示画面のPHPとは別のPHPで　CSVデータの提供を達成する、の解決策で
指示画面側にユーザ指定値が入力されるケースではどういった対応手順を検討すべきなのでしょうか？
データセット（配列？）の取得までは指示画面側のロジックを流用したい、というのはやはり怠惰な考え方でしょうか
想像以上に初心者ですみません

====更に追記====
CSV出力のために別PHPを動作させる方法が分からなく　現在も試行錯誤中です．．．。以下に示したコードでは『CSVファイルにデータ以外のHTMLが現れている状況です』。

EXECとやらを利用するのでしょうか？？上部の$stmt->execute();の結果を別PHPで利用するようなことを達成したいのですが．．．。試しにheader関数部分のみを別PHPに記載してこのPHPをEXECで呼び出すようにしてみたら、当該phpがエディタとしてあがってくるだけでした。
またcubickさんのご見解で「HTML中にPHPを埋め込んで」との記載がありましたので、/htmlの下でPHPを再開させ　header関数部分のみを記載するようにしてみましたが、状況は変わらず『出力されるCSVファイルにデータ以外のHTMLが現れていしまう状況でした』。
CSV出力の実行指示画面はTableを生成して表示するPHPも兼ねているので、現在のところHTMLの中でTeble用のDB抽出も行ってしまっている状況です。
考え方を改めるべきか、ただ単に別PHPの起動方法を理解すべきなのか、ちょっと分からなくなってしまいました。
どうすれば、CSVにデータのみを出力できるのでしょうか？

```
$stmt->execute();       //★流用したい

//★テーブルのページインデックス押下か、検索ボタン(submit)押下
if (!isset($_POST["extbtn"]) || $_POST["extbtn"] != "CSV") {
    $recset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $recCount = count($recset);
//★ＣＳＶボタン(submit)押下
} else {                    

    $file_path = "sample.csv";
    $export_csv_title = ["申請№", "№", "種別", "受領書確認", "営業所名", "担当者名", "受注先名称", 
    "施設名称", "出庫日", "品名CD", "品名名称", "容量", "ロット№", "数量", "単価", "金額", "経費負担部所", 
    "受付予定者", "受付結果", "受付実施者", "受付実施日", "承認予定者", "承認結果", "承認実施者", 
    "承認実施日", "更新日", "社内備考"];

    foreach($export_csv_title as $key => $val) {
        $export_header[] = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'SJIS-win', 'UTF-8');
    }

    if (touch($file_path)){
        $file = new SplFileObject($file_path, "w");

        $file->fputcsv($export_header);

        while($row_export = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $export_arr = "";

            foreach( $row_export as $key => $val ){
                $export_arr[] = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'SJIS-win', 'UTF-8');
            }
                                                $file->fputcsv($export_arr);
        }

        $dbh = null;

        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=temporary.csv'); 
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
        readfile($file_path);
    }
    exit;
//goto lb_finish;
}
//****以降　テーブル表示・ページインデックス生成のコーディング
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答に、submitされたボタン内容を確認するサンプル　を追記しました。

Comment: "ＣＳＶボタン(submit)押下"について、"goto lb_finish;"ではなく ダウンロード処理が完了したら、"exit;"で終了させる。　理由：'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'を出力後、殆どのブラウザーは以降の送信データを保存し表示しない（画面の更新もしない）為

Comment: @yyz 文面を改めている間に行き違いが起きてしまいました

Comment: どうすれば、CSVにデータのみを出力できるのでしょうか？<-処理の最後は exit; 完全終了すると出来ると思います。動作確認サンプルをcsvfile.php名で保存して動かすと確認できると思います。

Comment: @yyz　引き続きのご支援誠にありがとうございます。
早速goto文のところをexitにしてみたのですが、残念ながら状況は変わりありませんでした。
後から申し上げて申し訳ないのですが、CSVに出力されるべきレコードが途中までしか落ちていません。
この事象は関係ないですよね？？？こちらの問題が解決してから本格的に確認しようと思っていましたが
万が一に関係しているかもしれないのでこの場で言及致しました。

自分の適応能力のなさに嫌気がさしてきました

Comment: @yyz ご報告です。サーバ側に仕上がっているCSVファイルを確認してみると、DBから抽出したレコードのみであり、
ほぼ期待どおりの内容が収まっていました（ほぼ=最後の列にシーケンシャルな行番号が現れてる点が不明）
当方利用ブラウザはIEですが、本文に添付したダイアログが下部に現れるので
このダイアログに従って仕上がったCSVファイルを開くなり、保存した後に開いてみると
HTMLが含まれた形態（ファイル）になっていることを発見しました。

もう少し早く気がつくべきでした。本文に画像を追加しました。

Comment: SplFileObjectで、openした新規ファイルを明示的にcloseしていないからデータが不規則なのでは無いでしょうか？

Comment: ご支援をありがとうございます。
故意にSplFileObjectをcloseさせる意味合いで、$file = null; という構文を
header関数の前に挿入して、readfile($file_path)の後ろにはexit; を挿入しているのが現況です。
やはりダウンロードするファイルにHTMLが含まれてしまっている状況です。

PHPでのCSVデータ出力の参考文献は沢山ありますが、こうも当方が苦労しているのは
当方の摘要方法が根本的に間違っている、ということでしょうか？
それともサーバ上に仕上がったCSVファイルは相応の形で仕上がっているので
ブラウザ（IE）・当方のクライアント端末の設定か何かの問題なのでしょうか？

Comment: headerの出力部分で誤りがあります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考までに、phpからcsvデーターをダウンロードさせる、もっと単純なコードサンプルです。
（注意、色々な事を省略しています。あくまでも動作確認サンプルです。）

```
<?php    if(isset($_GET["download"])){

        $filename = $_GET["filename"].'.csv';

        $csv_a = array("NO","日付","フラグ","タイトル","名","姓","ファイル名","ファイル名２","ファイル名３","ファイル名4","リンク先","速度","タグ....");
        $csv_b = array("10987654321","2017-10-19","a1","data1","data1","data1","file1","file2","file3","file4","link1","30","タグ1","タグ２","タグ３","タグ４","タグ５","タグ６","....","タグｎ");
        $csv_c = array("10987654321","2017-10-19","a1","data1","data1","data1","file1","file2","file3","file4","link1","30","タグ1","タグ２","タグ３","タグ４","タグ５","タグ６","....","タグｎ");

        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        echo mb_convert_encoding ( implode(",", $csv_a),'SJIS-win',"UTF-8")."\r\n";
        echo mb_convert_encoding ( implode(",", $csv_b),'SJIS-win',"UTF-8")."\r\n";
        echo mb_convert_encoding ( implode(",", $csv_c),'SJIS-win',"UTF-8")."\r\n";
        exit;
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="get" action="csvfile.php">
        <input name="filename" type="text" placeholder="csv file name">
        <button type='submit' name="download" value="download">download</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**追記**
submitされたボタン内容を確認するサンプル （test.phpとしてファイルを作成）

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] === 'csv'){
    echo 'csv<br>';
}elseif(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] === 'disp'){
    echo 'disp<br>';
}
if(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] === 'incsv'){
    echo 'incsv<br>';
}elseif(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] === 'indisp'){
    echo 'indisp<br>';
}
foreach($_POST as $key=>$data){
    echo $key.' : '.$data.'<br>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <button name="send" value="csv">csv</button>
    <button name="send" value="disp">disp</button>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="incsv">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="indisp">
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2" value="text2">
    <input type="text" name="text3" value="text3">
    <input type="text" name="text4" value="text4">
    <input type="text" name="text5" value="text5">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: いつもご支援ありがとうございます、本文に追記を図りました、ご確認頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: いつもご親切な対応大変ありがとうございます。
name属性を同一にするINPUT要素（submit）を配置すれば切り分けられるのですね？？
全く気がつきませんでした、本当に．．．。
引き続きCSV出力の対応を再開したいと思います、とても助かりました。

Comment: レコードセット的な内容を別PHPに渡すような解決策を思いつきましたが、その方向は間違いないでしょうか？
間違いない場合、どういった記述になるのでしょうか？なんかまたとんでもない勘違いを私はしているのでしょうか？
本文に再度追記を図りました、ご確認を頂けますと本当に本当に助かります．．．

Comment: 本文に追記しましたがクライアント側で取得されるCSVファイルについてもDBから抽出したデータのみを収めたいのですが対策はあ‌​るのでしょうか

Comment: いつも御世話になっております。ご提示頂きました例同様、html外のコーディング部分へCSV出力・header関数一式を記述したことで
無事問題（ダウンロードされるファイルにHTMLが含まれる）が解消されました。一重にcubickさんyyzさんのご親切な対応のお陰です。
CSVデータの出力という面で、他2点の課題を残しているので、別案件で掲載したいと考えています。いつもすみません．．．

Answer (score 1):

参照先の例ではPHP単体にアクセスするとブラウザにCSVデータをダウンロードさせる仕組みです。
同じように「CSV出力用のPHP」と「PHP呼び出し=ダウンロードボタン表示用のHTML」という様に別々にファイルを用意し、HTMLページからPHPを呼び出すようにしてはどうでしょうか。

質問文に書かれたような、HTML中にPHPを埋め込んで**自分自身**を呼び出してしまうと、HTML部分の記述が邪魔をして意図した動きにならないのではないかと思います。

Comment: いつもご支援ありがとうございます、本文に追記を図りました、ご確認頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 指示を受付けるWebページのコーディング中でCSV出力も対応する方針は維持して
仰られるように、header関数を含むCSV出力部分をhtmlの外部にもってきました。
すると．．．問題に捉えていた
ダウンロードするファイルにHTMLが含まれてしまう事象はなくなりました。
一先ず問い合わせの主旨は解決しました、ありがとうございます。